# Validating data entered on the form page : WPF

Tags: validation, wpf-controls, binding

I have around 20 controls which are binded to different properties of a class along with validation rules like following. For sake of understanding i am writing the code for one control as other are same.

```
<TextBox  Style="{StaticResource errorStyle}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,100,0,0" Name="balesText" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" >
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource insertTransaction}" UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit" Path="Bales">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <ExceptionValidationRule/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

Right now i am checking for the input errors in code-behind in the following manner

```
BindingExpression balesBe = balesText.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
balesBe.UpdateSource();
.
.
if (balesBe.HasError)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please correct Errors", "Insert Aborted");
        }
        else
        {
            Binding insertTransactionBinding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(balesText, TextBox.TextProperty);
            InsertTransaction insertTransaction = insertTransactionBinding.Source as InsertTransaction;
            insertMessage = insertTransaction.Add();
            MessageBox.Show(insertMessage, "Transaction");
            this.NavigationService.Refresh();
        }
```

Now, the Question is : **Is there any way i can validate these 20 controls in  one go or i need to manually define their `BindingExpression` and check for validation error??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your own UserControl "OwnTextBox". Inherit it from TextBox (`OwnTextBox: TextBox`) and define there DependencyProperty Validate. Then you only have to remember, that TextBox is part of logical tree and make search from it.